# yield and WWWForm error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to convert the code at (the 2nd sample on the page): http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html

..to C# in Unity3D:

```
void Start () 
{   
    string dataUrl = "http://www.my-site.com/game/test.php";
    string playName = "Player 1";
    int score = -1;

    // Create a form object for sending high score data to the server
    var form = new WWWForm();
    // Assuming the perl script manages high scores for different games
    form.AddField( "game", "MyGameName" );
     // The name of the player submitting the scores
    form.AddField( "playerName", playName );
     // The score
    form.AddField( "score", score );

    // Create a download object
    WWW downloadW = new WWW( dataUrl, form );

    // Wait until the download is done
    yield return downloadW;


    if(downloadW.error == null) {
        print( "Error downloading: " + downloadW.error );
        return false;
    } else {
        // show the highscores
        Debug.Log(downloadW.text);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> error CS1624: The body of `rr2game.Start()' cannot be an iterator block because`void' is not an iterator interface type

After doing some reading I have tried changing void Start() to IEnumerator Start()
..but it says IEnumerator is is not declared..?

If I comment out the yield command the errors go away, but of course the data doesn't load.

Please can someone help?
Thank you.

Comment: Have u used System.Collections namespace to use IEnumerator

Comment: I finally got it working as I wanted by asking on answers.Unity3D.com , see:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/43732/problem-with-yield-and-www-inside-start-function.html

Comment: Yield keyword should be used in a method that returns an Enumerable or an Enumerator. The way it is introduced in unity material can be misleading, look into how C# uses this on MSDN then see how Unity takes advantage of it to implement coroutine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yield can not be used in the Start() function, it needs to be called within its own thread, instead try this:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SaveScore());
}

IEnumerator SaveScore() 
{   
    string dataUrl = "http://www.my-site.com/game/test.php";
    string playName = "Player 1";
    int score = -1;

    // Create a form object for sending high score data to the server
    var form = new WWWForm();
    // Assuming the perl script manages high scores for different games
    form.AddField( "game", "MyGameName" );
     // The name of the player submitting the scores
    form.AddField( "playerName", playName );
     // The score
    form.AddField( "score", score );

    // Create a download object
    WWW downloadW = new WWW( dataUrl, form );

    // Wait until the download is done
    yield return downloadW;


    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(downloadW.error)) {
        print( "Error downloading: " + downloadW.error );
    } else {
        // show the highscores
        Debug.Log(downloadW.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"yield can not be used in the Start() function,"* yes it can, you just need to make it return `IEnumerable` instead of `void`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the return type of `Start()`, the `Start` callback supports both `void` and `IEnumerator` as it's return types.

```
IEnumerator Start () 
{   
    string dataUrl = "http://www.my-site.com/game/test.php";
    string playName = "Player 1";
    int score = -1;

    // Create a form object for sending high score data to the server
    var form = new WWWForm();
    // Assuming the perl script manages high scores for different games
    form.AddField( "game", "MyGameName" );
     // The name of the player submitting the scores
    form.AddField( "playerName", playName );
     // The score
    form.AddField( "score", score );

    // Create a download object
    WWW downloadW = new WWW( dataUrl, form );

    // Wait until the download is done
    yield return downloadW;


    if(downloadW.error == null) {
        print( "Error downloading: " + downloadW.error );
        return false;
    } else {
        // show the highscores
        Debug.Log(downloadW.text);
    }
}
```

Once the return type is `IEnumerator` you are allowed to use the `yield` keyword.

Most callbacks let you return `IEnumerator`, some that can't are: Awake, Update, LateUpdate, FixedUpdate, OnGUI, OnEnable, OnDisable, OnDestroy. You will need to check the documentation of the event callback to see if it does not support being a co-routine.